# Why are CSS animations and transitions blocked by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance, css

**Update 2:**

Running the JSFiddle below, in Chrome 31.0.1650.34 beta now **does not** result in the described behaviour i.e. it does not "freeze as the JavaScript kicks in". I can only assume they have placed the CSS transitions on a separate thread from JavaScript, and the rest of the page—good news! The freezing/blocked transition still does appear in Firefox 25.0.

**Update 1:**

@IvanCastellanos mentioned that CSS transitions and animations are **not** blocked on Android Chrome. This is extremely useful information, and partially motivated this question.

**Original Question:**

This might be more of a question for the browser vendors, but here goes: Until now I was under the impression from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=iYdfj0XxoMY) (and others) that transitioning CSS opacity wouldn't really suffer from *any* performance issues.

In the video Paul Irish specifically gives the impression that transitioning opacity just isn't going to be a problem and "anyone that tells you otherwise is just ...wrong".

Well, if that's the case, **[this fiddle makes me wrong](http://jsfiddle.net/4J8q7/1/)**.

**Why is the CSS transition being blocked by JavaScript, given Paul's extraordinary claims?** This is also the case for animations, what's going on?

(For those of you either not seeing what I'm seeing, or too lazy to view the fiddle: I see a red square make it about 1/5 the way through a fade-in transition and then freeze as the JavaScript kicks in, then the squares jump to the end of the transition to full opacity, presumably because the duration has been reached during JavaScript execution.)

Given that stackoverflow is requiring I post some code because I'm linking to jsfiddle, here's the relavant JavaScript and CSS:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var isVisible = false;

    function handleClick() {

        var fadingSquare = document.querySelector(".fadingSquare"),
            i;

        if (isVisible === false) {
            fadingSquare.className = fadingSquare.className + " active";

            // Do something intensive in JavaScript for a while
            setTimeout(function () {

                for(i = 0; i < 10000; i += 1) {
                    console.log(i);
                }

            }, 200);    // Make it occur midway through the CSS transition

            isVisible = true;
        } else {
            fadingSquare.className = fadingSquare.className.replace("active", "");
            isVisible = false;
        }

    }

    document.addEventListener("click", handleClick, false);
}());
```

And CSS:

```
.fadingSquare {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #F00;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
}

.fadingSquare.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: *"Given that stackoverflow is requiring I post some code becuase I'm linking to jsfiddle, here's the relavant JavaScript and CSS"* AND it's good practice in any case.

Comment: Then the policy works!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The selected answer is a bit out of date. As of today on OSX safari, firefox, and chrome all run css animations in separate thread from javascript.

Comment: Interestingly though, the FF 54.1 update just broke it for me, and JavaScript code now _blocks_ non-layout transitions.

Comment: that's not true at all. before the loop is done not even an animated gif will be able to run - none, nothing, nada.

Comment: @BekimBacaj -- I'm afraid you are wrong, already running CSS animations, CSS transitions, and Web Animations API animations which do not require frame-by-frame layout and/or other style computations will continue running even if the main thread is blocked. We use this in our [webapp (AudioNodes)](https://audionodes.com/online), and it works in Chrome, FF, Edge.

Comment: @Dave Because `left` requires layout, which runs on the main thread, and is thus blocked by your loop (you are really not supposed to animate layout-related properties anyways). Try with `transform`, the animation won't block.

Answer (score 9):

Javascript runs on the browser's UI thread.

The *entire page* is blocked by Javascript; not just CSS transition.

Comment: Which is pretty much what I thought, until I heard Paul et al. claiming that there wouldn't be *any* performance issues.

Comment: @Matt There aren't any performance issues when transitioning opacity. There are performance issues when you write crap JavaScript.

Comment: Ha ha, touché. Fortunately, the JavaScript isn't mine but YouTubes (there's some irony for you). Nevertheless, videos such as the one referenced above give the wrong impression regarding performance and CSS. I'm always going to use CSS over JS animation, but it *does* come with its own gotchas.

Comment: BTW console.log is extremely expensive.

Comment: @IvanCastellanos That's the point, I was demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Android Chrome does what you were expecting (run outside the UI thread): http://www.phpied.com/css-animations-off-the-ui-thread/

Comment: Ah ha! I saw a video on that very topic, but couldn't find it and thought I'd made it up—which is why I was so confused. Thank you for confirming my suspicions and clearing up my confusion.

Comment: Newest FF 40.0.3 OSX doesn't support css animations running in separate thread. In http://www.phpied.com/css-animations-off-the-ui-thread/ kill-button freezes all animations.

Comment: @TimoKähkönen Transitions run in separate thread on FF 54.0, but interestingly, not on FF 54.1.