# Why can't speed be changed on CSS animation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I've made a CSS animation and some JavaScript code to update the animation speed. It seems that my JavaScript code is valid but that once the speed is set in CSS it can no longer be updated. If I don't set the speed in CSS the JavaScript works perfectly fine.

```
#circle1 {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background: blue;
   -webkit-animation: upDown 5s infinite;  /* Safari and Chrome */
   animation: upDown 5s infinite;
}
```

If the last two lines in the css above are removed the following javascript works

```
document.getElementById('circle1').style.webkitAnimationName = 'upDown';
document.getElementById('circle1').style.webkitAnimationDuration = '40s';
```

See this JS fiddle for more details http://jsfiddle.net/usJv8/1/

Comment: Seems like a bug in Chrome, it's setting `-webkit-animation: 40s` instead of `-webkit-animation-duration: 40s`.

Comment: Hmm... even applying the style in dev tools won't take effect until I turn the animation off and then re-apply it

Comment: And applying the entire animation shortcut has no effect, though dev tools indicates it has been applied. http://jsfiddle.net/usJv8/2/

Comment: Would this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368087/why-are-css-animations-and-transitions-blocked-by-javascript?rq=1

Comment: It's supposed to work either way for Webkit, but try capitalizing the first character in the JavaScript attribute... Browser prefixes can be weird like that: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thebeebs/archive/2012/01/11/with-vendor-prefixes-what-is-the-javascript-equivalent-of-ms.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's a rendering issue (you'd need to re-render the element to visualize the changes). I came with a "solution" that I don't know if it will work for you, as it is based on removing and then re-appending the element to the DOM:

```
document.getElementById('circle1').style.webkitAnimationDuration = '40s';

var aux = document.getElementById('circle1');
document.getElementById("maincenter").removeChild(document.getElementById('circle1'));
document.getElementById('maincenter').appendChild(aux);
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/usJv8/9/ (notice that I added an id to the center tag)

Comment: Since it's probably not @PhilipK's intention to immediately change the property in onload but on click or defered this will break the animation and my guess is, that Philip wants it so, that the ball will continue its animation in the middle of the way with lower speed.