# Cordova freeze UI during long Javascript while

Tags: javascript, freeze, visual-studio-cordova

I can't create a working example, but the code is simple.

---

**Configuration**

**IDE:** *Visual studio 2017*

**Target platform:** *Windows x64*

**System:** *Win 10*

**My project:** *Javascript // Blank App (Apache Cordova) // ver. 6.3.1*

---

**HTML // index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header></header>
        <main>
            <div id="cal">

            </div>
        </main>
        <footer>
            <!-- ## this creates a simple pure css loader ## -->
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="indeterminate"></div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class=".addItem">Add</a>
        </footer>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>

        <script src="frameworks/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="frameworks/materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>        

        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

**Javascript // index.js**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";


    document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

    function onDeviceReady() {

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.addItem').on('click', function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    loadCalendar();
                }, 5000);
            });

        });

    };


    function loadCalendar() {
        var i=0;
        while (i <= 10000) {
            var html = '<div class="row"></div>';
            $('#cal').append(html);
            i++;
        }
    }


} )();
```

---

App starts and the UI work as expected, the `progress` loader show his css animation. After clicked the button `addItem` all work for 5 seconds and then the UI freez until the `while loop` end. I don't think it is normal, **how can I solve it ?**

*Thanks*

### **Edit**

**An important clarification**

I don't expect the DOM to be updated during the loop, and this code above is not the real code, it is only usefull for understanding and test. The real loop is much shorter and faster, but it is still a problem.

**What happens is that the whole interface freezes, the whole app. The CSS animation should be totally independent from Javascript, but is freezes!**

[Here an example of what I expected](https://jsfiddle.net/6va70L78/)

*I hope this clarify the point better.*

Comment: All JavaScript loop declarations are "blockers"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment, all loop declarations are blockers, and before the loop has finished - even the most trivial hover effect will not be able to respond.

JavaScript is linear, synchronous and a single-threaded process. To circumvent the freeze condition, you will need to move your loop operation on to a separate thread.

E.g.: On another - separate instance, of a document!

Comment: Take a look at my clarification :)

Comment: Yes but my explanation still stands - I already noted that it will put on hold even the most trivial (css) hover effect. {css is not independent, it too needs to be interpreted by the same engine.}
Put your head in use I already gave you the solution. Interpret it! :)

Comment: I do not know why I assumed that JS was run as a separate thread from the rendering engine. There would be no need for methods such as `requestAnimationFrame` for animations. My stupid conviction has made me lose a lot of time! The UI browser engine is in single thread ... stop, you're right. I will look at the `web workers` as possible solutions, thanks.

Comment: But this is an interesting point: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44169400/4031083 and this is an online test (a little bit old) of a css multithread animation: http://www.phpied.com/css-animations-off-the-ui-thread/. To add interesting information.

Comment: well moving css animations to transform, and making it asynchronous  in some sense means removing the element not only from document flow but create a separate entity. Similar to having a Chinatown in Berlin or the use of `embed` element. There's always a trade-off  in these decision matters. Browsers taking these decisions should start looking back - trade offs always bite back. There's a good reason behind the fact that we humans and every animate alive are also single threaded entities.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is to be expected.  You're calling

```
$('#cal').append(html)
```

10,001 times.  Each time you do this you're modifying the DOM which is an expensive operation.

If you really need to write out 10001 div class='row' elements you might be better off writing them all to a string then doing one append. It's still not ideal but it's hard to see a better solution without knowing more about what you're trying to achieve.

```
function loadCalendar() {
    var i=0;
    var html = '';
    while (i <= 10000) {
        html += '<div class="row"></div>';
        i++;
    }
    $('#cal').append(html);
}
```

Comment: in fact no append operation will be executed during the loop as they will be stacked and appended in one turn only after the loop breaks out. Your `html+='<div class="row">...` will take / create the same amount of freezing time.

Comment: Yes, good point. The DOM will still have the same number of elements to render on the next tick. You might shave off a few milliseconds depending on the cost of jquery find and jquery append but probably not much.

Comment: Take a look at my clarification :)