# Background position animation (placehold shimmer / skeleton loader) stops during page load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a placeholder shimmer effect (skeleton loader) in lieu of a datatable whilst it loads. The datatables data is retrieved from the server and passed to a master function which 1) hides the shimmers 2) does several dom updates 3) inits the datatable 4) inits the datatable editor (in that order). Unfortunately, as execution hits this function the shimmers freeze in place for a good two seconds.

Obviously, this is pretty heavy resource usage in terms of starting the datatables and the editor addon as well as the dom writes. However, my understanding was that the CSS animations etc are now handled by Chrome in a different thread, so this shouldn't happen.

I did try to recreate in codepen, but with just the basic datatables initialization it doesn't stop the shimmer - so perhaps it is the resource usage? Can anyone suggest what could be going on? Thanks in advance

The HTML in use consists of several rows of

```css
@keyframes placeHolderShimmerSmall {
  0% {
    background-position: -500px 0
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 500px 0
  }
}

.animated-background {
  will-change: transform, opacity;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: placeHolderShimmerSmall;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  background: $skeletonLightGrey;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #eeeeee 10%, #dddddd 18%, #eeeeee 33%);
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex contents-table-loading-row">
  <div class="animated-background contents-table-loading">
  </div>
  <div class="animated-background contents-table-loading">
  </div>
  <div class="animated-background contents-table-loading">
  </div>
  <div class="animated-background contents-table-loading">
  </div>
  <div class="animated-background contents-table-loading">
  </div>
  <div class="animated-background contents-table-loading">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My bet would be that blocking javascript is taking too long.

Either batch the work and dispatch it asynchronously with `setTimeout`, or, use a web worker ?

Can't help you much more than that without actual code

Comment: That's what I assumed as well. However, based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368087/why-are-css-animations-and-transitions-blocked-by-javascript I thought that javascript no longer blocked animations. I have tried using the setTimeout in several places (like wrapping the datatable and editor init functions) and it does appear that the datatables is causing the issue, but I've had no success in prevent the shimmers from stopping.